# Column 'id_member' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an error in code :

> Column 'id_member' in where clause is ambiguous

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1052

Column 'id_member' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT *, `aa`.`id_member` FROM `tb_permohonan` `aa` LEFT JOIN `tb_member` `bb` ON `aa`.`id_member`=`bb`.`id_member` LEFT JOIN `tb_jenis_uttp` `cc` ON `aa`.`id_jenis_uttp` =`cc`.`id_jenis_uttp` WHERE `id_member` = '1'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/web/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

this my controller:

```php
public function v_print_surat() 
    {   
        $start  = intval($this->input->get('start'));
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id_member');
        $data_where   = array('id_member', $id);
        $print        = $this->Tb_permohonan_model->get_by_where($data_where);
        if ($print) {
            $data = array(
                'print'     => $print,
                'start'     => $start, 
                'content' => "frontend/v_print_surat",
            );
            $this->load->view('layout/frontend', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('frontend'));
        }
    }
```

this my model:

```php
function get_by_where($data)
    {   
        $this->db->select("*, aa.id_member");
        $this->db->where($data[0], $data[1]);
        $this->db->join('tb_member bb','aa.id_member=bb.id_member','left');
$this->db->join('tb_jenis_uttp cc','aa.id_jenis_uttp =cc.id_jenis_uttp','left');
        return $this->db->get($this->table." aa")->result();
    }
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent ambiguous column you should make the *"where"* clause to be more specific. Since you are aliasing `$this->table` to `aa`, you could change :

```php
$this->db->where($data[0], $data[1]);
```

to

```php
$this->db->where('aa.' . $data[0], $data[1]);
```